# Usage of postgresql_select on macports

Tags: postgresql, macports

On macports, there's a package called postgresql_select

Is this intended as a utility to select a current active version of postgresql (assuming I have multiple versions of postgresql installed on my Mac)?
If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
sudo port select --set postgresql postgresql90
```

Where "postgresql" indicates the group in which we want to set and the second argument "postgresql90" is the version we want to make as default.

However, at this time of writing, setting to postgresql91 is not working correctly, reference https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31335